# React useContext problem with Typescript -- any alternative to <Partial>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a React app that uses useContext, and I'm having trouble getting the typing right with my context. Here's what I have:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import endpoints from '../components/endpoints/endpoints';

interface contextTypes {
    endpointQuery: string,
    setEndpointQuery: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
    searchInput: string,
    setSearchInput: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
    filmSearch: string | undefined,
    setFilmSearch: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
    pageIndex: number,
    setPageIndex: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>,
    resetState: () => void;
}

export const DisplayContext = createContext<Partial<contextTypes>>({});

interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

const DisplayContextProvider = (props: Props) => {
    const { nowShowing } = endpoints;
    const [ endpointQuery, setEndpointQuery ] = useState(nowShowing);
    const [ searchInput, setSearchInput ] = useState('');
    const [ filmSearch, setFilmSearch ] = useState('');
    const [ pageIndex, setPageIndex ] = useState(1);

    const resetState = () => {
        setSearchInput('');
        setFilmSearch('');
        setPageIndex(1);
    };

    const values = {
        endpointQuery,
        setEndpointQuery,
        pageIndex,
        setPageIndex,
        filmSearch,
        setFilmSearch,
        searchInput,
        setSearchInput,
        resetState
    };
    
    return (
        <DisplayContext.Provider value={values}>
            {props.children}
        </DisplayContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default DisplayContextProvider;
```

The problem is, when I use `<Partial<contextTypes>>`, I get this error all over my app:

`Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`

Is there a way to fix this so I don't have to go around adding `!` marks to everything where I get the undefined error? (I'm also pretty new to Typescript, so it's totally possible that I'm going about typing my context in completely the wrong way)

Comment: `createContext<contextTypes>({} as contextTypes);` ?

Comment: Partial means that some keys are missing and it's  unknown which ones. So ! is needed, or preferably a check that a key is defined. If this isn't what it is then don't use Partial.

Comment: @Adam Mann, why not store an initial state to pass into createContext that is the same shape (instead of Partial)? That way, each property in the shape is known to be defined.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova, wow that worked. Seems so simple, but the ```as``` trips me up because I've never had to use that syntax. Guess I need to dig into how to use that.

Comment: @AdamMann `as` is similar to '!', with '!' you tell TS "I know it's not null" and with `as` - "I know it is of type X, even if it doesn't look like". If you're confident that the context will be initialized before it is used, you can as well pretend it is already initialized :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you can't initialize the context with a useful default value, but you expect that the context provider will always be higher in the component tree.

When I'm in this situation, I want the following behavior:

- If a component tries to use consume the context but the provider wasn't used above it, throw an error
- Components consuming the context should assume the context has been set.

So, I usually create a hook that wraps useContext and does the null check for me.

```
import React, { useContext, createContext } from 'react';

interface contextTypes {
    // ...
}

// private to this file
const DisplayContext = createContext<contextTypes | null>(null);

// Used by any component that needs the value, it returns a non-nullable contextTypes
export function useDisplay() {
  const display = useContext(DisplayContext);
  if (display == null) {
    throw Error("useDisplay requires DisplayProvider to be used higher in the component tree");
  }
  return display;
}

// Used to set the value. The cast is so the caller cannot set it to null,
// because I don't expect them ever to do that.
export const DisplayProvider: React.Provider<contextTypes> = DisplayContext.Provider as any;
```

If `useDisplay` is used in a component without a `DisplayProvider` higher in the component tree, it will throw and the component won't mount.

Comment: This is the best practice in my opinion and it has saved us from debugging a couple of times already.

Comment: I was actually using ```export const DisplayContext = createContext<contextTypes | null>(null);``` before, but I kept getting the error ```...does not exist on type 'contextTypes | null'``` in my components. Maybe because I was setting up the Provider differently than you are here? Typescript w/ React seems to have so many quirks that I feel like I'm going by trial and error

Comment: I'm guessing you were using the result of `useContext(DisplayContext)` before verifying that the result is non-null, which would explain why TypeScript was complaining. That's what the `useDisplay` function does, it checks for null and throws, so your components don't have to. This isn't a quirk or bug: You _could_ try to use the DisplayContext without another component having set DisplayContext.Provider above, so TypeScript forces you to _prove_ that the value is non-null.